# high cpu usage in fabric 1.0.0

Tags: python, fabric

In fabric 0.9, everything runs OK, but in 1.0.0, the following fabric script shows 100% CPU usage in `top`:

```
from fabric.api import run

def test():
    run("sleep 1000")
```

I'm running the file like this:

```
fab -H localhost
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Me too. Destroys my machine. What python are you running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue which will hopefully be addressed in a day or two:

http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/312