# limit time for command

Tags: python, fabric

I run command: run('sleep 1000'). How to limit time ( for example 100) for this command ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you what to achieve!

Comment: Please do what? Your question is of poor quality.

Comment: I think Bdfy means the run command in fabric, as per this other question of his: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266851/high-cpu-usage-in-fabric-1-0-

Comment: I think sleep is just an example, he wants to know if with fabric you can fail/kill/abort a run() if it exceeds a preselected amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Several points to be precised in your question

- your question is not really a python one, but is more focused on the **sleep** command, right ? I did not find any `run` command for any standard python package... Or you may want to use python's `time.sleep` instead ??
- I guess you want to set a max value for the sleep command, to be used if the value passed is greater... Is this ok ?

If so, in case you use `time.sleep`, there is no way to do what I suppose you want to, as [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941177/upper-limit-in-python-time-sleep) shows; I did not find any other way to limit the **sleep** command either via online documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The closest functionality Fabric provides for that would be [fabric.operations.prompt](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/0.9.0/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.prompt). It can validate the input and set default inputs as optional add-ons.